# Problem with CiviCRM configuration (auto_increment) with wordpress (4.x) website

Tags: wordpress

According to the folks at Network Solutions (our website hosts) the plugin (CiviCRM 4.7.4) was installed.
They had to do a MySQL upgrade database as part of “routine” updates also.  The MySQL upgrade
went fine in that it did not crash our website or cause us to have to make any repairs to the info on the site.
The configuration of CiviCRM is where the problem lies.  According to Network Solutions, there are requirements
that the CRM needs that are blocked on the MySQL server as potential security issues.  They said an “auto_increment_increment” needs
to be set to 1.   So there is my dilemma. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear how setting `auto_increment_increment=1` constitutes a security issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Your hosting environment sounds unsuitable for running CiviCRM - CiviCRM does have some additional requirements beyond other PHP/MySQL apps like Wordpress and Drupal.

There are some places in CiviCRM code where it expects the database to increment IDs by 1. Where MySQL is running with eg replication, this will not be the case. There are also places where CiviCRM has checks for such settings, which are mostly to protect you against unexpected outcomes - even if there's no hard requirement for that setting to be the way CiviCRM "wants" it to be.

For your needs, the simple solution is not to address replication or patch CiviCRM, but simply to obtain hosting which is compatible with CiviCRM. Unless you are *heavily* invested in the existing hosting, switching hosts to someone who knows & works with CiviCRM will be a much more straightforward solution than trying to make CiviCRM and that hosting service work together ...

- [CiviCRM's page on hosting](https://civicrm.org/hosting) (not an advert, just trying to save you time, money and grief)

For more technical detail, there's a related question from a site which specifically wanted to use MySQL replication + CiviCRM together - JIRA issues linked there:

- [MySQL Master-Master Replication on 2 servers](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7395/mysql-master-master-replication-on-2-servers)

Comment: NB: Reading that linked question, it looks like @ExGerman found the installer worked fine once the check was disabled ... but it sounds like your site isn't at the installer stage anyway, so either there are other `auto_increment=1` requirements in the codebase or ... IDK. Regardless, you'll be best off with someone who knows how to work well with CiviCRM if you have that option :)