# Website Hosting and CiviCRM

Tags: hosting

I redesigned a website for a local nonprofit using Wordpress that is currently hosted with Network Solutions.  After I finished the website for them, they started looking into finding a database for those who donate/buy tickets for their organization, and they ultimately settled on CiviCRM.  However, when they tried to install and configure CiviCRM for the site, the final configuration could not take place due to a glitch saying that the setting of the "auto_increment_increment" needs to be set to 1.  The nonprofit and I have been looking into the issue online, and ultimately we were informed that the underlying issue was that CiviCRM is not compatible with Network Solutions for security reasons or something along those lines.  ([Problem with CiviCRM configuration (auto_increment) with wordpress (4.x) website](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/problem-with-civicrm-configuration-auto-increment-with-wordpress-4-x-website))

I am at the point where I'm considering transferring the website's hosting from network solutions to one of the recommended hosts listed on your website.  Before I do so, I just wanted to run our situation by you folks one last time to make sure that we're taking the right course of action.  I will admit, I am very new to web design, so my knowledge of things such as this is rather limited, so hopefully I'm not missing anything obvious.  Hopefully my query isn't too vague.  Let me know if you require any additional information.

Comment: this sounds like a replay of http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/problem-with-civicrm-configuration-auto-increment-with-wordpress-4-x-website and you may find the comments there by my colleague Chris helpful

Comment: Short version of [my answer to the question you've linked](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/11354/149): If the hosting company doesn't support CiviCRM, [switch to one that does](https://civicrm.org/hosting). You'll do much better when what you're doing is fully supported by the folks servicing you, and mass-hosting environments often don't cater well to specific needs.

Comment: Totally agree with Chris Burgess, move to a hosting company that supports CiviCRM, so get one from the list.

Answer (score 4):

CiviCRM has very specific hosting requirements, so it is always best to select a hosting provider that advertises compatibility with CiviCRM. The CiviCRM hosting providers directory (https://civicrm.org/hosting-providers) is your best place to find such hosts.

Comment: That's so very true!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively: working with a partner https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors - will not only help you select/find a suitable hosting environment for your civicrm project - this will also help you get the most out of your civicrm!